# hosting reportportal instance with apache

Tags: apache, reportportal

I am trying to host the reportportal instance in Apache. I have installed reportportal with docker on ec2 instance and it's working properly. Now I am trying to host that in the webserver. I have used apache as a webserver.
I have followed this https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_web_server_ubuntu/ link and I installed apache and configured the virtualhost.My virtualhost looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName x.xx.xx.xx
ServerAlias myhost.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/reportportal
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I can start the server without any issue for example sudo systemctl start apache2.
In browser when I try to naviagate to myhost.example.com I am getting forbidden error

```
You dont have permission to access this resource
```

Let me know do we have any other proper way to host this as webaplication?

Answer (score 1):

Report Portal does not run on Apache Web server, since it was written on Java, Go and Python.

But it is possible to deploy it through shell installation using embedded Tomcat server. To do this please follow instructions here: https://github.com/reportportal/shell-installation

Answer (score 0):

There are two recommended ways of hosting the ReportPortal:

- Docker
- Kubernetes

ReportPortal consists of multiple modules (e.g. servers running), so without virtualization instruments you will have to host and configure all of them manually. However, it is still possible, have a look at [this guide](https://reportportal.io/docs/Deploy-ReportPortal-without).
Since Amazon was mentioned, the recommended way of installation would be to use Kubernetes, hosted on AWS premises. Installation guide [can be found here](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/tree/master/reportportal#cloud-computing-services-platform-installation)